# Intellij: identify Maven dependencies based on variables in pom

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven project with multiple dependencies in my pom.xml like so:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.dept.team</groupId>
            <artifactId>package1</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6-${releaseType}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.dept.team</groupId>
            <artifactId>package2</artifactId>
            <version>${releaseVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
```

I understand using `mvn compile -DreleaseVersion=myVersion -DreleaseType=myType` from the command line to indicate to the Maven process what the variables are, but how do I configure IntelliJ to recognize the packages based on these variables? I'm on IntelliJ Ultimate 2022.3.

Comment: did you try setting the versions through properties in pom.xml and using the values in the version tag?

Comment: @Neenad I don't want to update the properties tag since I'm using git and don't want my changes to be committed. In addition, this doesn't work when I select Reload All Maven Projects in the Maven sidebar.

Comment: Try VM options in  `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing/Runner` and `Properties` in `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner` which could set these.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do what you want.   From within IJ, go to the Maven tool window and navigate to the Lifecycle part of the tree show.   Right click on the "compile" task and select "Modify Run Configuration".

That will create a run configuration and open the edit run configuration dialog.  Name it something like Compile R1V2 or whatever is appropriate.

Then use the "Java Options|VM Options" section of that dialog to set the -D defines for the configuration then hit "Ok" to save.

Now you can select that run configuration using the Run Configuration drop down.  You can create as many of those as you like with whatever permutations if -D values you like.